# Keep Javascript constant the same after function is recalled

Tags: javascript, global-variables, constants, dynamic-list

I am trying to create a dynamic list so when the user performs a search it will repopulate the list. The problem is that I can't seem to make an immutable constant to store the original div content. Every time the function get's called this variable gets reinitialized.

Is there a way to achieve this without using cookies ? Any help is sincerely appreciated. The code is not complete because I couldn't get passed this step but if you think I am totally heading toward the wrong direction please let me know.

**const originalList = document.getElementById('patientList').getElementsByTagName('li');
frozen = Object.freeze(originalList);**

```
  <script>
    const originalList = document.getElementById('patientList').getElementsByTagName('li');
    frozen = Object.freeze(originalList);
    var newList = '';
    var found = false;
    function filterPatients(){
        var searchQuery = document.getElementById('search');
        var query = searchQuery.value;
        var listContainer = document.getElementById('patientList');
        var patientList = listContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < originalList.length; i++){
            var link = patientList[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
            var link = link[0].text;
            /** remove whitespaces for easy comparison **/
            link = link.toLowerCase();
            query = query.toLowerCase();
            link = link.replace(/\s/g, "");
            query = query.replace(/\s/g, "");

            /** check every character in query **/
                if (link.length > query.length && link.substring(0,query.length) == query){
                    found = true;
                    newList += '<li>' + patientList[i].innerHTML + '</li>';
                }
        }
        if (found == true){
            listContainer.innerHTML = newList;
            newList = '';
        }
        else{
            listContainer.innerHTML = "<li>No patient by that name</li>";
        }
        console.log(frozen);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: What browser are you running this code in?

Comment: @Daniel Granger, I tested the code on firefox, chrome and safari all with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalList = document.getElementById('patientList').getElementsByTagName('li').cloneNode(true);
```

Make originalList a copy of the element. Currently, you are setting originalList and patientList to be the same list of elements, so changing one will also change the other. Use element.cloneNode(true) to make a deep copy of a DOM element

Comment: thank you, I will try this option and let you know. I got around it by creating a duplicate list in html and set the style to hidden. I know both these options are not optimal but yours is definitely better.

Comment: I guess you can't call cloneNode directly. Had to do it like this.            const orignalContainer =     document.getElementById('patientList').cloneNode(true);
const originalList = orignalContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');